# Teamcity agents disconnecting after build (cannot access agent)

Tags: java, docker, teamcity

I have installed teamcity on my server and it resides in a docker container. I have 4 Windows servers running the Build Agents services. However, it seems the teamcity server cannot see the agent after starting a build. I can't find anything in docker logs or in teamcity logs. The agent logs literally show

> [2019-07-29 16:30:16,055]   INFO - r.agent.impl.AgentLogProxyImpl -
>   Failed to perform remote command 'pingAndReregister' for build with id
>   174629, error: java.lang.Exception: Unable to register on server, not
>   pingable: java.lang.Exception: Unable to register on server, not
>   pingable (enable debug to see stacktrace) [2019-07-29 16:30:17,089]
>   WARN -    jetbrains.buildServer.AGENT - Ping problem:
>   jetbrains.buildServer.xmlrpc.RemoteCallException: Call 'url', method
>   'buildServer.ping' failed: java.net.ConnectException: Connection
>   refused: connect

The agents re-connect after a little while but then disconnect again once a build commences.

This just started happening recently, it was fine 2 weeks ago.. anyone else seen this issue?

Comment: can you ping from agent machine to TeamCity server? does 9090 port are open in the agent ?

Comment: Have you checked the ping result from Server to agent and visa versa.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there was a duplicate DNS entry for the teamcity server in Samba which was confusing the agents!